# Pandas - Finding the intersection of values in two dataframes, return a single dataframe of same size with number of intersections

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I am looking for a way to return a (n x n) Dataframe in which each value of the dataframe is the number of intersections between the values of the two dataframes (both of which are size n x n).

I am not really sure how to do such an operation between two dataframes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
df1
              0             1
0  [4, 7, 3, 5]  [4, 7, 3, 5]
1     [8, 2, 6]     [8, 2, 6]
2  [9, 1, 8, 2]  [9, 1, 8, 2]
3        [3, 5]        [3, 5]
4     [9, 4, 8]     [9, 4, 8]
5     [0, 1, 4]     [0, 1, 4]

df2
              0             1
0  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]
1  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]
2  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]
3  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]
4  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]
5  [2, 3, 6, 9]  [6, 2, 3, 5]

df3 - intended dataframe to be returned
              0             1
0             1             2
1             1             2
2             2             1
3             1             2
4             0             0
5             0             0
```

Edit: fixed mistake on example result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmmh, i have no way to do this with pandas directly, i only have a solution for dicts. And i think you have an error in your example result, i think my result is the intended result.

```
import pandas as pd

# Prework to get your data
data = {0: [[4, 7, 3, 5], [8, 2, 6], [9, 1, 8, 2], [3, 5], [9, 4, 8], [0, 1, 4]],
        1: [[4, 7, 3, 5], [8, 2, 6], [9, 1, 8, 2], [3, 5], [9, 4, 8], [0, 1, 4]]}

data2 = {0: [[2, 3, 6, 9], [2, 3, 6, 9], [2, 3, 6, 9], [2, 3, 6, 9], [2, 3, 6, 9], [2, 3, 6, 9]],
         1: [[6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 3, 5]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# ---

dc = df.to_dict()
dc2 = df2.to_dict()

new_dc = dc.copy()
for key in dc:
    for val in dc[key]:
        new_dc[key][val] = len(set(dc[key][val]).intersection(dc2[key][val]))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dc)

print(new_df)
```

output:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  2
2  2  1
3  1  2
4  1  0
5  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and pre-work. I did not know about the strength of dictionaries and their use in solving these questions. Much appreciated. Thanks again!